# GridLayout setAdapter

Tags: adapter, android-gridlayout

I need to notify an image inside the Gridlayout is changed.
Using the GridView it is easy:

```
adapterForImage.notifyDataSetChanged();
gridview.setAdapter(adapterForImage);
```

How can I do with the GridLayout?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout isn't tied to an adapter like GridView is.  My suspicion is that you just want to use something like a CursorLoader, which will automatically register a content observer.  When the content associated with the provider changes, you can invalidate the whole GridLayout --- or you can invalidate just the views that you know need to be updated.